# Find control in templated WPF datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get value of checkbox from datagrid? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311882/get-value-of-checkbox-from-datagrid-c-sharp)

I am trying to find a control inside the selected row in a templated DataGrid.

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Local">
                 <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                           <CheckBox Name="chkImport"  IsChecked="{Binding IsLocalized}"></CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

I am trying the following code:

```
   var selectedRow = (DataGridRow) gridFileScan.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(gridFileScan.SelectedItem);                           

   CheckBox chkImport = FindVisualChild<CheckBox>(selectedRow);
```

but chkImport is always null. Any ideas ??

Comment: Are you using the FindVisualChild implementation from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311882/get-value-of-checkbox-from-datagrid-c-sharp

Exactly what you need.

Comment: @Yatrix FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(selectedrow) returns NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. I just had to call this method after modifying ItemsSource:

```
  gridFileScan.UpdateLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you debug you should be able to see the method recurse the VisualTree.

You can see the Visual Tree by using [the Visual Tree Visualizer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/01/29/using-the-wpf-tree-visualizer-vstipdebug0004.aspx)

The implementation of FindVisualChild might be flawed or the VisualTree doesn't look like what you expect.

Comment: Thanks Erno. I didn't know that this tool existed. 
Anyway, the DataGridRow is empty. I have no idea why!! See this screenshot http://img11.imageshack.us/img11/6082/visualtree.png

I am handling the SelectionChanged event.

Comment: Yes, of course. But not in the event SelectionChanged where I am executing my code. 
I am adding some extra items to ItemSource but they don't appear in this event.